# How to calculate the coefficients for each level of random effects using lmer

Tags: r, sas, lme4

my name is NOZOMI. I'm a biostatistician in Japan.
I am trying to ask questions in English for the first time.
I apologize if my English is difficult to understand.

I used `lmer()` in the lme4 package to analyze the mixed effects model.
Standard errors of the coefficients of each level of the random effect differed from the results calculated by SAS.
As a side note, the point estimates were close between R and SAS.

I will upload the scripts and outputs of R and SAS, so please tell me how to describe the script in R to match the standard error in SAS.

To emphasize, I'm not interested in which default analysis method is more appropriate in R or SAS, I just want to know what script I can use to get the same results.

[R script]

```
model <- lmer(y ~ f + (1|r),data=data)
coef_random <- tidy(model, effects="ran_vals", conf.int=T)
```

[R output]
[image: R output]

[SAS script]

```
proc mixed data=data ;
 class r ;
 model y = f / cl ;
 random r / cl ;
run ;
```

[SAS output]
[image: SAS output]

Comment: Given that the point predictions are the same, I have very little idea why the estimated conditional standard deviations are so different (e.g. 5.92 for group 1 in R vs 9.4259 in SAS).  Probably way too late to answer this question, but I might attempt it if I had a [mcve] ...

Comment: @BenBolker
Thank you very much.
More than a year after I asked the question, I still don't know exactly why the standard errors are different.
The random number used for the analysis was created in Excel and cannot be reproduced in code.
Therefore, the files are shared via Dropbox. Sorry for the inconvenience.
[Share files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mgylm2x0w6lum0c/AADPinOYk93oPmz_iGqkO0ooa?dl=0)